# Spring using multi-user database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, datasource

I am working on a web application, everyone has their own database with the same table schema, the database is created when the user sign's up.

How can I create a database when the user sign's up and how can I assign a data source to each user.

I am using Spring MVC 4 and hibernate 4.

I already made some research but all that I came up with is some 7 years old posts and I think they are outdated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: a better approach would be to have one database and in your tables keep a reference to the owner that _owns_ the data.

Comment: http://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/Make-your-Spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/

Comment: i can't do that du tu the huge amount of data every user will have